# What is the relationship between a JavaScript Object and an element created in it?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, createelement

Is it possible to pass this.brother as a variable in the eventListener of this.son?

```
function Object(a){
  this.brother = a;
  this.son = document.createElement("div");
  document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(this.son);
  this.son.addEventListener('mousedown',function(){ 
    onMouseDown(event,this.brother);
  });
}
```

User input changes the value of this.brother later on,so i cannot just pass the input variable *a*.

Do I have to add a new eventListener everytime the value of this brother changes?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking, and the code provided doesn't seem a working code, could you rewrite your question with a [mcve]? I am mainly refering to the `this` component, and how you expect these to change in the future, also a function called `Object` is just asking for problems

Answer (score 2):

Your question basically comes down to what the keyword `this` means inside a function. There are three options.

**1. "Proper" functions**

```
this.son.addEventListener('mousedown', function() { 
  onMouseDown(event, this.brother);
});
```

If you define a function with the complete function definition syntax, `function() {}`, then **`this` will refer to the object through which the function is invoked.** In the case of an event listener, it's the object that you defined the listener on, which in your case is the `div` you created. This means you'll get an error, because `div` elements do not have a property called `brother`.

**2. Arrow functions**

Arrow functions were introduced in more recent years, and use different syntax:

```
this.son.addEventListener('mousedown', () => { 
  onMouseDown(event, this.brother);
});
```

Arrow functions work exactly like "proper" functions in every way, with one exception: they do not have their own `this`, i.e. **`this` will refer to whatever it refers to in the scope where the function is defined.** In your case, it will refer to the object you're initializing in your `Object()` function. This is probably the one you want.

*(Side note: You really shouldn't name your function `Object`, that name is already taken by the base class for all objects in JavaScript. Overwriting it can cause all sorts of trouble)*

**3. Bound functions**

Functions in JavaScript are objects, and thus they also have methods. One of these is `bind()`, which allows you to create a bound copy of the function:

```
this.son.addEventListener('mousedown', (function() { 
  onMouseDown(event, this.brother);
}).bind(this));
```

Bound functions also work like "proper" functions, except **`this` will always refer to the object you passed as the argument to `bind()`**. Before arrow functions, bound functions used to be the most widespread way to ensure `this` always refers to the same object within a scope. After arrow functions appeared they started to fall out of favor, since arrow functions are more efficient and produce more readable code.

Comment: Great answer despite my sloppy question, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna suggest this but you can use a bound function:

```
function _Object(a){ //this is not a great function name
  this.brother = a;
  this.son = document.createElement("div");
  document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(this.son);
  this.son.addEventListener('mousedown',(function(event){ 
    onMouseDown(event,this.brother);
  }).bind(this));
}
```

As for your question, no you do not have to update it.this refers to the _Object, if the brother pointer is changed, this.brother will point to the new brother.